# how do I remove nested select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a Name table with the columns
NameID
Name
TypeID

With the following SQL

```
SELECT[NameID]
FROM[Name]
WHERE[TypeID] = @TypeID
AND NameID >= (SELECT MIN([NameID]) 
               FROM [Name] 
               WHERE [Name]='Billy' AND [TypeID]=@TypeID)
```

Ive been asked to convert this to an Inner Join without using any nested select but not sure how to.
thanks for your help!

Comment: The subquery is evaulated only once (it isn't a correlated subquery). It shouldn't be a performance problem. Every other way I can think of writing the query will be less efficient.

Comment: Is this an exercise? Why was it deemed to need rewriting?

Comment: Hi Lukas, 
I was just asked to remove the nested selects from our SQL scripts, I dont have enough of a SQL background to argue against why I shouldn't do it, hence the posting on here.

Comment: Assign the result of the subquery to a variable and use `WHERE TypeID = @TypeID AND NameID >= @MinNameID` in the original query. It will do the same and whoever told you to do this will be happy, without realizing you didn't change anything. :)

Comment: :) I will do this, thanks Lukas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Originally I didn't think you needed a join at all,

```
;WITH n AS 
(
    SELECT
      NameID,
      rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY NameID)
    FROM [Name]
    WHERE TypeID = @TypeID
    AND [Name] = 'Billy'
)
SELECT NameID
    FROM n
    WHERE rn > 1;
```

Then again, maybe I do not have the requirements clear.  What is the purpose of this query?

```
SELECT n1.NameID 
FROM [Name] AS n1
    INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT NameID = MIN(NameID) 
    FROM [Name]
    WHERE TypeID = @TypeID
    AND [Name] = 'Billy'
) AS n2
ON n1.NameID >= n2.NameID
WHERE n1.TypeID = @TypeID;
```

I agree with Lukas, I am not sure why the person who is telling you to change this thinks an inner join will be better than your original.

Comment: Not really an equivalent, the original query will return more rows than where Name='Billy'.

Comment: Yeah I am trying to understand the purpose of the original query.

Comment: Ive been asked to do it for performance reasons, I've been instructed that Iner Join is faster.

Comment: You should compare them.  Since every query, data set etc. is different, nobody can possibly "instruct" you that INNER JOINs are always faster, because that simply isn't true.

Comment: Plus, I meant the purpose of the query in the first place.  What question does this query answer?

Comment: Hi Aaron,
Ive changed the names of the parameters as in our database they refer to names that would be meaningless unless you know the jargon for what they refer to.

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the nested part via: -

> declare @NameID int
>
> select @NameID = (SELECT MIN([NameID])
>   FROM [Name] WHERE [Name]='Billy' AND
>   [TypeID]=@TypeID)
>
> SELECT [NameID] FROM [Name] WHERE [TypeID]
>   = @TypeID AND NameID >= @NameID

But as stated already, this does not provide any performance benefit as the subquery would only be evaluated once in your version, the same as in this.

Answer (score -2):

Well, it looks like just moving the condition `[Name]='Billy'` should produce the same result for this specific query. So convert your original:

```
SELECT[NameID]
FROM[Name]
WHERE[TypeID] = @TypeID
AND NameID >= (SELECT MIN([NameID]) 
                   FROM [Name] 
                   WHERE [Name]='Billy' AND [TypeID]=@TypeID)
```

to:

```
SELECT[NameID]
FROM[Name]
WHERE[TypeID] = @TypeID
AND[Name]='Billy'
```

Comment: Would those that rate the answer down (or others that did not) be so kind to point out where the logic is flawed and/or does not answer the question? Cheers.

Comment: I tested this.
If I have a table

NameID TypeID Name
------ ------ ----
1      1      Billy
2      1      John 
3      1      Billy
4      1      Billy

Comment: Then the nested select returns 1 as the value (when @TypeID is 1)

The query would then return ID's 1,2,3,4 (ie Billys and John)
whereas your query would only return 1,3,4 (just Billys)

Comment: ps apologies for the formatting, and Van thanks for the input, as I say, I'm learning SQL so even checking why your SQL didn't work was a worthwhile excercise for me :)

Comment: good point, fair enough, thanks. I assumed that there can be just one "Name" for each "NameID".